# Null Pointer exception on firebase to check isEmailVerified

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication, null-pointer

I want to check the mail registered to my app is verified or not. So I implemented a signin button to do this. But when I click on this button, a null pointer exception caught on the android studio and app crashed at the time.

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()' on a null object 
 reference
```

My code snippet is

```
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
     sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (user.isEmailVerified()){
                signin();
            }
            else {
              startActivity(new 
            Intent(SignInActivity.this,MailVerify.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone please help me to fix this.advanced thanks ...

Comment: [`getCurrentUser`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) returns null if no user is signed in

Answer (score 1):

`mAuth.getCurrentUser();` return `null` if has no user singned.

Update your `if` statement to:

```
if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()){
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
})
.onSuccessListener(new On.....);
```

and on Successful Login i.e in onSuccessListener use getCurrentUser() method on mAuth to prevent null point exception on which .isEmailVerified() would work.

for more reference refer : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth